# Recording system audio with AVFoundation

Tags: macos, avfoundation

Apple has mad it easy in OS X to record the screen using AVCaptureScreenInput in AVFoundation, but it does not include the system audio. Is there a way to record the system audio as well? Perhaps a way to grab system audio as an AVCaptureInput as well?

Comment: Hi Chad were you able to figure out how to do this? I was also in need of this.